# Running Docker commands included in a shell script alongside other Linux commands and switching users

Tags: shell, docker

Using the Linux terminal, I run bash scripts (.sh files) containing sequences of commands I want to execute.

The issue is that I am unable to run a Docker command from within my shell script. I can run this Docker command when it's typed directly at the terminal with root privileges but not when I include it in the shell script file.

My script executed as a general user from command line, looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/user/docker_backup
# remove /home/user/docker_backup/data
rm -rf data
# Switch to root privileges. my system is set to only run Docker as root
su
# Copy a folder from Docker container to host OS 
docker cp <container-name>:/home/user/data /home/user/docker_backup
# More general user commands
cd ..
```

My code only runs until the `su` line above. After i enter the root password, nothing happens. if i type `exit`, i get permission errors, meaning the `docker cp` command failed.

Comment: I don't think you can just switch to root privileges with `su`. Try executing the command with `sudo` instead of adding `su` above.

Comment: @samprog i have a root account so when i use ```su``` it prompts for my root password and i enter it and then shows my command line as root

Comment: This is expected behaviour. You switch your current user to root during the script, but the script was executed by your own user. So the `docker cp` command will also be executed as your own user, but you will be logged into the root account. This results in you not seeing the output of `docker cp` (which might give you insight to not working - I think insufficient privilege).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually posting this as an answer:

You switch your current user to root during the script, but the script was executed by your own user.

So the `docker cp` command will also be executed as your own user, but you will be logged into the root account.

This results in you not seeing the output of `docker cp` (which might give you insight to not working - I think insufficient privilege).

A solution to this is either using `sudo` before `docker cp`, starting the script as root or adding your user to the group "docker", which authorizes your user to use the `docker` commands

Comment: Thanks @samprog for you quick response. ```su root -c <command>``` did not work. Also i can switch between root and user and run commands with their privileges with my current script

Answer (score 3):

**

### This is my desired solution

**
After thorough research, as I wanted to run my script as a general user, and only run certain commands as Root when necessary, I came up with a solution that works.

My script now looks like this (run with 
`$ sh script_name.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/user/docker_backup
# remove /home/user/docker_backup/data
rm -rf data
# Switch to root privileges. my system is set to only run Docker as root 
su - root -c "docker cp <container-name>:/home/user/data /home/user/docker_backup"
# More general user commands
cd ..
```

Run shell script as general user. For commands that require root privileges, I use `su - root -c "<command>"`. Terminal prompts for root password and executes command in quotes as root, then shell proceeds as general user.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue where the docker commands were running fine on the Terminal but the same commands were not running when I compiled them into a bash script and the issue was basically because of two reasons.

1. The docker commands need to be run with uplifted privileges that is with the sudo command ( Eg: **sudo docker ps**  works but docker ps won't work). One could add the current user to docker group so that we need not use sudo with each docker command. Please visit [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) link and follow the section 2 to do the same.
2. Run the script in the correct way

   1. One should have **#! bin/bash** at the starting of the script. It is a *shebang* that is required by each script.
   2. One should save the file **without .sh extension**
   3. One should provide the execution permission to the script by giving command **chmod 777 script_name**
   4. run the script with **bash script_name**